# Switch between actions bars in WOW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there any way to move switch between your action bars (Gold arrows in the image) with a shortcut?

[image]

Comment: It is important to note (not sure if this is still the case though) that when you enable the extra action bars (bottom left, bottom right, and the 2 on the right hand side) that the amount of alternative bars for the bar in the picture above decrease accordingly. So if you only enable 2 additional action bars, you will have 2 bars less on the scroll wheel method mentioned below by [Williham Totland](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9401/williham-totland). I see now that this was mentioned by [Christian Ivicevic](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/21550/christian-ivicevic) in a comment.

Comment: @HowlinWulf: This is only partially true; bars 3 through 6 can still be accessed using Shift-3 through Shift-6; only Shift-Scrolling will skip them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the standard setup Shift-Scrollwheel and Shift-1 through Shift-6 should do the trick nicely.

Comment: You can also change these keybinds through the standard WoW keybinding preferences, should you prefer a different shortcut.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Indeed; a strictly speaking complete answer might be a simple "Yes." ;)

Comment: Moreover it is possible to edit options in the Interface menu, such that more action bars are displayed such that you don't need to change the page to use some skills.

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>⇑SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>⇑SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> in order to accomplish this task.